# How to add custom close icon for Alert component in Material UI, globally

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, customization

We can globally customise the severity icons shown in the Alert component through the theme:

```
  MuiAlert: {
    defaultProps: {
      iconMapping: {
        info: <Info/>,
        success: <Success/>,
        warning: <Warning>,
        error: <Error/>,
      }
    },
    styleOverrides: {
    ...
    }
```

But, is there a way to do the same for the close icon, the one displayed when the [OnClose](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/04869a58fd4219149fcef920328bd7c3d80f6e72/packages/mui-material/src/Alert/Alert.d.ts#L64) prop is defined?

```
  /**
   * Callback fired when the component requests to be closed.
   * When provided and no `action` prop is set, a close icon button is displayed that triggers the callback when clicked.
   * @param {React.SyntheticEvent} event The event source of the callback.
   */
  onClose?: (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => void;
```

I know the alternative solution is to create my own styled component derived from the Alert component and set the my custom close icon, but would like to avoid that and see if it is possible through the theme components customisation.

Otherwise I think it would be a nice to have and maybe should open a request for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible! Looking at the [MUI Alert api docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/alert/) there is a prop `components` where you can define the icon you want to display for the close icon, same with the button.

Then when you create your custom theme you can simply add that `components` prop to the `defaultProps`.

Note that we're not passing the actual `<HomeIcon />` but just the function.

```js
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Alert from "@mui/material/Alert";
import HomeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Home";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiAlert: {
      defaultProps: {
        // The default props to change
        components: {
          CloseIcon: HomeIcon,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default function DefaultProps() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Alert onClose={() => {}}>Your alert with custom icon :)</Alert>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```